# resize the image to 128x128 before upload

Tags: php, file-upload

Can someone of you please help me here on how to get the uploaded image resized into 128x128 pixels?

would really appreciate your help here.

here is my bit of upload code

```
$countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $countfiles; $i++) {
        $filename = date('Y-m-d-his').'-'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $target_file = 'uploads/logos/'.$filename;
        $file_extension = pathinfo(
            $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);              
        $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);
        $valid_extension = array("png","jpeg","jpg");       
        if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension)) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$target_file)){
                }
            }       
        }
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Take a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787006/12452679 https://stackoverflow.com/q/3786968/12452679